# SQL Server division query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run the query:

```
select (100/50)
```

It give me 2 - good.

But when I run the query:

```
select (50/100)
```

I was expected it will give me 0.5... but it gives me 0 instead? Why? and How can I get the 0.5?

```
select (25/(30))*100
```

I was expected it will give me 83.33 but it also gives 0 instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you divide two integers, the result is an integer as well, so 50 / 100 is 0.5, which is an integer of 0.

To get a decimal point, either write:

```
Select 50.0 / 100
```

or Cast the integer o a decimal - i.e.

```
SELECT (CAST(20 AS DECIMAL(5,1))/30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select (50/100.0)
```

Using an integer for division will lead to zero if the result is less than 1 because `integer` values can only be round numbers.

`0.99` will result in the lower value = `0`
`3.876` will result in `3` and so on.

Use `decimal` variables to get the result you want. You can easily do that by using a `.` in your numbers: `100.0`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server considers your numbers as int and gives an int result.

try

```
select 100.0/50

select (25.0/(30))*100
```