# SQL Server - Why calc is giving 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to write a case statement as below

```
case when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date, current_timestamp) >104 then 0
     when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date, current_timestamp) <=13 then 1
     when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date, current_timestamp) between 14 and 104 
     then cast(((datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date, current_timestamp)-13)/91) as numeric(6,5) end as multiplier
```

However this will not return a non 0.0000 value when the datediff returns a value between 14 and 104. To test this I have tried to get a  really basic test to work

```
declare @test as numeric(6,5)
set @test=72/91
print @test
```

I still get 0.00000? what elementary mistake am I making?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this instead

declare @test as numeric(6,5)
set @test=72.0/91.0

Comment: Thanks that explains the test but any idea why the case doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql):

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

`DATEDIFF(week,@datetime,@datetime)` returns an integer.

You're getting a problem here likely because you're dividing *before* you cast as a numeric value.  Alternately, it's because SQL Server sees that two outputs of the CASE expression are integers, so it makes the whole column an integer.  Remember that columns only get one data type.

Try:

```
case when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date), current_timestamp) >104 then 0.0
     when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date), current_timestamp) <=13 then 1.0
     when datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date), current_timestamp) between 14 and 104 
     then cast(((datediff(week,cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date), current_timestamp)-13.0)/91.0) as numeric(6,5)) end as multiplier
```

I tried to fix your missing parentheses, but may have missed some.

Also: The only reason I can fathom for `cast(cast(tourney_date as char(8)) as date)` is because `tourney_date` isn't already `date` or a `datetime`.  For God's sake store your dates as dates, not strings or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you could make it simpler by doing something like this

```
declare @tourney_date datetime = '2017-9-16 '
declare @new_date datetime = (select  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @tourney_date), 0))
select
case when datediff(week,@new_date, current_timestamp) >104 then 0
     when datediff(week,@new_date, current_timestamp) <=13 then 1
     when datediff(week,@new_date, current_timestamp) between 14 and 104 
     then cast(((datediff(week,@new_date, current_timestamp)-13)/91.0) as numeric(6,5)) end as multiplier
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server when you division 72/91 it's mean int/int result is int.

Example: (int) 0.79120 = 0

You can try:

```
declare @test as numeric(6,5)
set @test=CAST(72 AS DECIMAL(5,1))/91
select @test union all
select 72.0/91 union all
select (72*1.0)/91
```

You can see more information here: [SQL Server division query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800740/sql-server-division-query)